# crystal reports page footer not showing on the first page if no page header

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have several Crystal Reports (2008) and the layout I want on the first page contains report header (summary graph of data) and the page footer (text-box and number). This works just fine on 3 reports. But then there is this report which is not working.

I have positioned in this report exactly the same elements of the same sizes and of the same positions as in the other reports. Page setup is the same in all of them. But when the problematic report have the same report header size (18,75cm), which in other reports leaves the good space for the footer, the footer is not showing. When I decrease the size of the report header-section about to 17cm suddenly the page header pops up there together with the footer. As can be guessed, I don't want the page header appear in the bottom of the first page... it does not do so in the other reports.

What makes Crystal "think" that page header should be displayed before showing page footer?

Comment: if possible please post a screenshot of your report.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that. Can't see why it were relevant, either.